# RequireJS paths not work

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm new to RequireJS and trying to use it. I followed an example in RequireJS docs but there is some problem. I can load the `jquery` but not `app/shell`.

```
Root
 |__index.html
 |__javascripts
     |__main.js
     |__libs
     |    |__jquery.js
     |    |__require.js
     |__app
         |__shell.js
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script data-main="javascripts/main.js" src="javascripts/libs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl:'javascripts/libs',
    paths:{
            app:'../app'
        }
    });
require(['jquery','app/shell'],function($,shell){
    if($ && shell){
        console.info('Scripts loaded');
    }
});
```

**shell.js**

```
define(function(){
    "use strict";
    return{
        initModule:function(){
            console.info('Module init');
        }
    }
});
```

**Web Console Errors**

`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/javascripts/app../default.htmshell.js"`

---

`Error: Script error for: app/shell http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror`

**Node.js Express Console Error**

`GET /javascripts/app../default.htmshell.js 404`

Comment: `GET http://localhost:3000/javascripts/app../default.htmshell.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:34
Uncaught Error: Script error for: app/shell
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror`.Errors from chrome inspector.

Comment: It would be better to add this output to your question and format it so that the line breaks follow those you get on the console. In what I manage to read from what you post in your comment, I see a ``../default.html`` string that seems completely random and is not explainable from what you've shown in the question.

Comment: I added errors from web console and Express server console.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have multiple folder levels, you have to set your baseUrl as the root of your application. If you want to use `require(['jquery'])` instead of `require(['libs/jquery'])`, you have to specify the "alias" of it in your configuration.

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl:'javascripts',
    paths:{
            jquery: 'libs/jquery'
        }
    });
```

Comment: I know it Sir. I want to config paths to folder, not to JS file. So sorry for my poor English.

Comment: No problem! I've copy/paste your code in my local machine with your exact folder structure and was able to make it work without any problems in the filesystem and on localhost. I used jquery 1.10.2 and require 2.1.9.

Comment: I used same jquery and require version but not work for me. I used Node.js and Express for server. Can the problem cause by file system?.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding your main.js file explicitly after your requirejs script tag:

```
<script src="javascripts/libs/require.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
```

This will load your configuration file synchronously after loading requirejs thus making sure the paths are set before a module is called.
Hope it helps.