# What to do when "requirejs is not defined" error thrown?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I had cloned a project from GitHub but when I had run it on my device it had thrown some error.
the project link is

https://github.com/mram98/quizwebapp.git

Please help me on what to do.

I had included the error screen shoot in the main directory of the repository.

Comment: Where is your package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

The project is using `bower`. Once you have downloaded the project go to the project root and run `bower install` to install the dependencies

Comment: it is what it is showing when i had gave command  (bower install) inside the project root directory.                                                                                                      
 "   'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 0):

`requiredjs` is part of **NodeJs**
make sure you have configer Nodejs on your server

here this is might help [RequireJS paths not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761867/requirejs-paths-not-work)